# Spring with Jersey + Jetty challenge

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, jetty, jersey

I'm new to dependency injection w/ Spring and am facing a seemingly challenging scenario.

My application receives data from a legacy system over a plain old socket, does Interesting Things (tm) with the data, then uses an embedded Jetty instance to pump out Really Interesting Results (tm) via HTML5 Web Sockets.  Additionally, the Jetty server hosts a Jersey servlet that provides a RESTful interface to all of that Interesting Stuff (tm).

I'd like to use Spring to inject shared DAOs and application service objects into both the legacy side and into my Jersey resources.  This requires that an ApplicationContext be shared between the legacy components and Jersey.  It seems that I would need to create the application context, wire it to my legacy components and then pass the application context to the Jersey ServletContext when configuring the embedded Jetty server (which I'm currently doing programatically).

Unfortunately, it's not clear how I can pass an existing application context into the Jersey ServletContext.  Can it be done?  Is there a better approach?

I'd like to note that this differs from the other Jersey + Jetty + Spring questions I've found on SO, which don't require an application context to be shared outside of Jersey.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your code starting Jetty is something like:

```
Server server = new Server(...);
server.setHandler(new WebAppContext(...));
```

You can get the `ServletContext` from `WebAppContext` and set the SpringContext on it:

```
WebAppContext wac = new WebAppContext(...);
ServletContext sc = wac.getServletContext();
sc.setAttribute(WebApplicationContext.ROOT_WEB_APPLICATION_CONTEXT_ATTRIBUTE, springContext);
```